# How to pass json file to Nunit3 tests execution from command prompt

Tags: selenium, build-automation, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I have a json file which has my app url and other details. i am running my tests from cmd prompt using nunit3-console runner. how can i pass the json file as parameter to my tests execution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass test case parameters using nunit console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768723/pass-test-case-parameters-using-nunit-console)

Comment: ^ That's an auto-message, but that should help - I reckon you're after the `--params` flag. =)

Comment: @Chris is it possible to pass a json file from --params. could you give an example

Comment: Looks like you got it. :-)

Comment: @Chris Yes i found it

Answer (score 0):

Use --params=environment="path to file"