# how to execute test cases in better way for windows application using winappdriver and C#

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit, specflow, winappdriver

I am working on an existing test automation framework that uses the following for UI tests on a windows application:-

- C# for creating UI cases
- winAppDriver to interact with UI objects
- nUnit for validation
- specflow for BDD

I don't have much idea about microsoft projects. Here is a simple structure of the project:-

- Application

  - Source

    - Modules

      - features

        - Tests

Each test folder has a "app.config" file in it that supplies the config for the test to work like DB username, pwd, services urls etc.

We execute our test case from "Test Explorer" pane in VS Enterprise which is not the best way if the test cases need to be run remotely in jenkins. As I said I don't have much frame of reference when it comes to Microsoft apps. So, here are some questions to which I have been looking for answers; there seems to be no definite consensus online. Just curious to know how others are maintaining their projects. Here goes:-

1. is there a jenkins friendly way of running these test cases? using a cmd line or a runner file perhaps?
2. if I find a way to accomplish #1 how do I inject app.config properties at runtime?
3. how does one execute these cases on remote machine? Mine is a desktop windows app. What would a high-level strategy look like? I assume I will have to get a remote machine and install the app on that machine?

any pointers, resources to read about would be helpful. Just looking for a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are using nUnit, it has a default approach of running tests from console [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482507/how-do-i-install-nunit-3-console-on-windows-and-run-tests)
2. It looks like you need to pass parameters from the test runner into the runtime. You can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768723/pass-test-case-parameters-using-nunit-console)
3. Execute on remote machine strategy depends on your current infrastructure. E. g. if you are using Gitlab, you should set up the GitLab CI runner into your machine and set up the GitLab pipeline.

> looking for a nudge in the right direction

- See CI\CD test run best practices